# Location of USPS Mail Boxes

Tags: data-request, federal

Is there open data for the locations of USPS mail box locations? There are a number of sites that have this information like http://www.payphone-project.com/mailboxes/, but I'd like authoritative data.

Comment: Are you looking for drop boxes or mail boxes at like residences and buildings?

Comment: I'm looking for  the blue drop boxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow - this is way harder to find than I would have expected. I do think I found one potential lead for you from the source of truth (USPS themselves).

As part of their API offering (https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/documentation-updates.htm) there is a "Service Delivery Calculator" service which takes an origination and destination zipcode and tells you the drop boxes nearby and what time you need to get the mail there for it to arrive by a certain time. This *could* be used to create a dataset of all the dropboxes in a given zip code.

I hope there is a better way.

You might also considering emailing USPS API folks at uspstechnicalsupport@mailps.custhelp.com.